# To pass a component variable as parameter or assign it as a global variable

Tags: angular, ionic2, global-variables

I am in the process of refactoring my Angular2/Ionic2 code and wanted to know what is the best practice for my situation.

I have defined a variable in my component (this.questions) and need to use it in my service method. There are two ways I could see a solution for this problem.

1. I use a global variables service, assign this.questions in there and then access the variable in foo.service
2. Or just pass my this.questions component variable as an argument in my method.

In theory both ways should work, but what is the general consensus?

Example code below for number 2:
I have a component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text-answers',
  templateUrl: 'text-answers.component.html'
})
export class TextAnswersComponent implements OnInit {

  questions: Object;

  constructor(public fs: FooService) {
    this.questions = {1:"foo", 2:"Bar"};
    this.fs.doPrint(this.questions)
  }
```

In my foo.service.ts:

```
doPrint(foo){
    console.log(foo)
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way would be,

declare **questions object** in ***service*** itself. *I assume here that you want to use questions object in other components too*.

**service.ts**

```
questions:Object;

doPrint(){
    console.log(this.questions)
};
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
export class TextAnswersComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public fs: FooService) {
    fs.questions = {1:"foo", 2:"Bar"};
    this.fs.doPrint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hand! I ended up doing something similar to this and assigned fs.questions in my page.ts file.